# Python array in dict

Tags: php, python, web-services, slim

I have a dict with some values needed to use a PHP web service. This web service need an array in that dict of values. So I have this on my Python script :

```
data = {
        'resId'         : res_id,
        'collId'        : 'letterbox_coll',
        'table'         : 'res_attachments',
        'data'          : {
            'title'             : 'Rapprochement note interne',
            'attachment_type'   : Config.cfg[_process]['attachment_type'],
            'coll_id'           : 'letterbox_coll',
            'res_id_master'     : res_id
        },
        'fileFormat'    : Config.cfg[_process]['format'],
    }
```

When I print `data` I have this :

> {'resId': '655', 'collId': 'letterbox_coll', 'table': 'res_attachments', 'data': {'title': 'Rapprochement note interne', 'attachment_type': 'outgoing_mail_signed', 'coll_id': 'letterbox_coll', 'res_id_master': '655'}, 'fileFormat': 'pdf'}

But here is the return of my PHP webservice :

```
Array
(
    [resId] => 655
    [collId] => letterbox_coll
    [table] => res_attachments
    [data] => res_id_master
    [fileFormat] => pdf
)
```

The php WS use Slim framework with HTTP Request and Response from this framework, here is a piece of code :

```
use Attachment\models\AttachmentModel;
use Convert\controllers\ConvertPdfController;
use Convert\controllers\ConvertThumbnailController;
use Convert\models\AdrModel;
use Docserver\models\DocserverModel;
use Docserver\models\DocserverTypeModel;
use History\controllers\HistoryController;
use Resource\controllers\ResController;
use Respect\Validation\Validator;
use setasign\Fpdi\TcpdfFpdi;
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;
use SrcCore\models\CoreConfigModel;
use Resource\controllers\StoreController;
use Template\controllers\TemplateController;
use SrcCore\models\DatabaseModel;
use Resource\models\ResModel;

class AttachmentController
{
    public function create(Request $request, Response $response)
    {
        $data = $request->getParams();
        file_put_contents('/var/www/html/test.txt', print_r($request, true));
```

So my question is, why PHP retrieve the 'data' index like this ? And how I could send a array ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the array in your dict?

Comment: I don't understand your question. `$request->getParams()` is the method in that framework used to get post parameters.

Comment: Oh, you're asking why it says `[data] => res_id_master` instead of showing the nested array.

Comment: All I can think of is that you're not really showing the result of that call. You overwrite the `test.txt` file every time you call the webservice.

Comment: The fact I overwrite my file with file_put_contents is not the problem. After some looks, the $request var doesn't contains the 'data' array. I didn't have 'title', 'attachment_type' etc before getting the post data. I really didn't understand

Comment: The only other possibility is that the Slim framework doesn't allow nested objects, so it replaces the object with the last key.

Answer (score 2):

The `print_r()` command outputs like that.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

It looks like you HAVE an array.
Should you wish to save the array in JSON format, just do the following

```
$json = json_encode($someArray);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Shouldn't it show `[data] => Array ( [title] => 'Rapprochement note interne' ...)`?

Comment: Possibly? I think the op needs to edit the question if that's what he's really asking

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious. He's sending a parameter with a nested dictionary, but when he prints the parameter in the PHP script it shows a string there.

Comment: I admit it took me a few minutes to notice this discrepancy.

Comment: yeah exactly, @Barmar is right. I try to json_encode my data var, but it shows the same, not array in my <code>data</code> index

Comment: like you say under his question, it doesn't look like the proper call

Comment: call the webservice in your browser and check the inspector for the response. if it looks good there, the problem is in your PHP. If it looks wrong there, you have a problem with the python endpoint you called

Comment: Well I just tried with Postman and I get an array as I want. The problem is Python use the same endpoint, so maybe I did my data array wrong ?

Comment: right hold on. the API server is in python, or php? i assumed the API was python, and that PHP was calling the endpoint

Comment: The API server is on the PHP side, Python just consume web services

Comment: If POSTMAN returns the correct JSON when calling the PHP API endpoint, then there is nothing wrong with your PHP.

Comment: Yeah I think, that's why I'm searching for help about the construction of my 'data' index to be interpreted like an array in my PHP API..